# How can this Visual studio Resource warning be resolved or removed?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Anyone can help us here - we have been having this error for several months and had many a stab to remove it, but we still havnt figured out why its there or how to remove it. How is this warning resolved or removed?

> Warning   351 A custom tool 'GlobalResourceProxyGenerator' is associated
>   with file 'App_GlobalResources\GridLocalization.bg-BG.resx', but the
>   output of the custom tool was not found in the project.  You may try
>   re-running the custom tool by right-clicking on the file in the
>   Solution Explorer and choosing Run Custom Tool.

Comment: Silly question, but did you right click on the file and select "Run Custom Tool"?

Comment: Yep silly, and yes ofc we did ;)

Comment: @Oded: I also have this problem and "Run Custom Tool" doesn't solve anything. So I don't understand why this question is closed and silly. Just because of you are not familiar with this problem?

Comment: @Kamarey - It is closed because 5 members of the community found it lacking (as described in the area in grey, below). The silly part refers to the question in _my_ comment, not the question by the original poster.

Comment: Honestly guys this just needed some formatting, not to be closed. The intended question was obvious: "How do we resolve or remove this warning?" I made the edit myself and nominated the question for reopening, just to clear its Closed state, as it is a valid question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After checking out the csproj file and discussing it in the group, we came up with the following answer:

When the resources were added to the project they were added using the wizard. This wizard added the designer files also, so for each reasource file there was also a .designer file.

This was seen as something that was not needed for the language specific resources and the designer files were deleted.

However the csproj files maintained the custom tool reference.

Deleting this reference (to "GlobalResourceProxyGenerator") for each of these resource files removed the issue.

The issue is that Visual Studio 2010 does not automatically remove this tool reference when the designer files are removed manually, creating this warning.

Comment: So what is the solution?

Comment: remove the tool reference

Comment: Also works for the pesky `MsDataSetGenerator` which annoyed the hell out of me on a project with included XSD files.

Comment: But if you want it to run?

Answer (score 7):

In my case this was caused by a `<LastGenOutput>` entry in the csproj file that referred to a non-existent file. Removing that line got rid of the warning.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2017 I had the same issue with the following error

```
Warning A custom tool 'ResXFileCodeGenerator' is associated with file <snip name>, but the output of the custom tool was not found in the project.
```

Removing the reference to 
`<Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>` within the resource file declaration, fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In VS 2019, I also fixed the error:

Warning A custom tool 'ResXFileCodeGenerator' is associated with file , but the output of the custom tool was not found in the project.

By removing the reference to ResXFileCodeGenerator 
found within the project's  " .csproj"  file!